# creating sql connection does not work as intended

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem in my asp.net project.

I have created a SQL file called "MySqlDB" in the `app_data` folder.

Then I do

```
static string paath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/MySqlDb.mdf");
```

and

```
static string bla=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" +paath +;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

and after that

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(bla);
```

The problem is that whenever I open the SQL it says :

> SqlException was unhandled by user code.
>   An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Also, it says like the SQL Server does not exist there or could not be reached

if someone can help me find the problem i would be really happy

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried debugging what the actual value is in your paath variable? Have you then tried hardcoding that to see if it works?

Comment: i tried to get the place of the sql server to create the sql connection

Comment: Please, could you open SQL Server Configuration Manager and check that SQLEXPRESS instance is running on the local machine, on the same machine as the web app?

Comment: how do i get to the SQL Server Configuration Manager ?
p.s :i am microsoft visual studio 2013

Comment: @Ilay Uozon. SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed with SQL Server Express. Press start button and search for it. If it's not found you don't have SQL Server Express installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SQL Server Express is not installed with Visual Studio 2013, but sqllocaldb is indeed.

You can use the following connection string

```
static string bla=@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" +paath +";Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

static string bla=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='+ paath +';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

OR

static string bla=@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MySqlDb.mdf;User Instance=true"